# ios coredata - count (only) the 'many' in a 'one-to-many' relationship without reading

Tags: swift, core-data

I am using CoreData in my iOS app to persist two kinds of entities, each involved in a one-to-many relationship - Entity A has an array (NSSet) of Entity B.

So far, I have a TableView currently displaying all Entity A objects and the attributes for each.
What I want now is for each to also show the count of Entity B for each Entity A - but without going through the whole fetch process to load every Entity B from the CoreData database - I just want the count of Entity B.

To be clear, I only want to know how many of Entity B is referenced for each Entity A, I don't want to actually load the Entity B entities or any of their data.

Is this possible?

My existing code will load all Entity A entitys and (unfortunately) each of their Entity B sets. As you can see, the only value I end up using is the count of Entity B in the NSSet.
There must be a way to only retrieve said count instead of loading every Entity B entity?

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("EntityA", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
fetchRequest.entity = entity

fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 10

let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: false)   
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

let afetchedController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil) 

afetchedController.delegate = self

afetchedController!.performFetch()

...
...

let entityBs : NSSet = afetchedController!.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath).valueForKey("entityBs")!
let entityBcount = entityBs.count
```

Comment: How did you test that it's loading them all?

Comment: While scrolling, the tablet cpu usage spikes and the tableview scroll becomes staggered. None of my other coredata & tableview implementations have this issue. I assumed the nsset was the cause. I will test that assumption.